# problem in understanding of this context

Tags: phrase-meaning

> And, in turn, adaptation for new and evolving use cases will be a
>   **critical differentiator moving forward**. It’s important to note that this
>   **is no longer just a technology discussion**, and the lens must zoom
>   out to consider changes to the entire business model.

I don't know the meaning of this "critical differentiator moving forward" and "is no longer just a technology discussion"
I know the meaning of each word but I have problem in the meaning of whole sentence.

Comment: It's just a verbose / abstruse way of saying *the ability to adapt to changing circumstances will make a big difference in the future* (when hopefully our "adaptive technology" will stand out from the competition because it's different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And, in turn, adaptation for new and evolving use cases will be a critical differentiator *moving forward*. It’s important to note that this is no longer just a *technology discussion*, and the lens must zoom out to consider changes to the entire business model.

I've reworded these part below:

> And, in turn, adaptation for new and evolving use cases will be a critical differentiator **as we move forward**. It’s important to note that this is no longer just a **discussion about technology**, and the lens must zoom out to consider changes to the entire business model.

Hope it helps!